# Problema con path sdk_android_root sdk_android_home linux mint 19.2 cinnamon

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3, rutas

Holas:

Mi nombre es Rolando, y tengo un problema archi-documentado sobre "ionic cordova build android". Hace poco probaba mis aplicaciones sin problemas en dispositivo móvil, hasta que actualicé varios paquetes en angular y node.

Ahora aparece este error:

```
> cordova build android --device
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk (DEPRECATED)
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

> Configure project :app
Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/olox/Escritorio/temp2/p1/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 68

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
/home/olox/Escritorio/temp2/p1/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/olox/Escritorio/temp2/p1/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 68

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova build android --device exited with exit code 1.
```

Busqué mucho y probé distintas declaraciones de path en el fichero .bashrc, quedándome con esto, sin tener resultados:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/build-tools
```

- No sé que más proba antes optar por reinstalar todo de nuevo como última opción.
- he usado esto también: "source .~/bashrc", por si acaso.

Gracias de antemano a quien pueda aconsejarme. Saludos :)

Answer (score 0):

No había quitado "`sudo`" del comando, entonces solo debía ingresar

```
"ionic cordova build android".
```

Gracias a este post que aunque no era exactamente sobre idéntico problema me dio la respuesta:

https://askubuntu.com/a/827170